# firebase_analytics '' is an invalid event name

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to log user events using [firebase_analytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics) I followed the documentation

this my main() method

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: "test_app",
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

This is MyApp class

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
  static FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer =
      FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
        ...
        navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => const MainScreen(),
          'product': (context) => ProductScreen(
                analytics: analytics,
                observer: observer,
              ),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how I log event

```
body: TextButton.icon(
      onPressed: () async {
        await analytics.logEvent(
          name: 'test_event',
          parameters: <String, dynamic>{
            'string': 'string',
          },
        );
      },
      icon: const Icon(Icons.analytics),
      label: const Text("Test Analytics")),
```

why do I end up with this error

```
W/FA      ( 7136): '' is an invalid event name.
```

Comment: can you change the parameter name 'string' to any other name?

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't imported `Firebase Analytics`, import

```
import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';
```

first in your main file.

If the issue still persists, run the following commands:

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
./gradlew build
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in Firebase initialization

The documentation said to initialize Firebase like this but then I did I run into error that I needed to add a name

```
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
```

so I tried to add a name as above

```
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: "test_app",
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
```

this let the app start but I got the error when I tried to log any event

so I removed options and name from Firebase initialization line

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

and it worked fine.